# Getting this software to run on Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, wine, lutris

My professor would like me to use a software program he built in the 1990s, which is compatible with Windows98,2000,XP,Visa

The installation file comes with a .exe and an msi file (what is this?).

These files are here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DjI3DYY0viDrYi_mhTv_m04kfNRARQdx/view?usp=sharing

I can get the installer to run using Lutris, but I can't change the destination from the C drive (which I think it presumes exists by default).

Would anyone be able to help me, to get this Instant Structural Analysis (ISA) software to work.

Comment: If it's going to be installed in Wine, do you *need* to change the destination from C:?

Comment: I will try, maybe I should send you screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it working

Use play on linux, create a virtual drive in 64,select Academic Version as shortcut